# File Cannot Be Saved Because it is Write-Protected

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, version-control

I am using Visual Web Developer 2010 Express and I just added my files into Visual SourceSafe.   When I try to save files in Visual Web Developer, it says, "The file cannot be saved because it is write-protected."  It gives me the option to overwrite, but I don't know if that's how it's supposed to work.  Ideally, I will click save and it will save the various versions into source safe.  I've never used source safe before; my previous source-control system just enabled be to click "commit."

Comment: If you are trapped with VSS for now due to various reasons, I suggest you read this [VSS tutorial](http://www.kevingao.net/sourcesafe-vss-how-to).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Files under source control are marked as read-only to prevent accidental changes to files and only made writeable when you check them out for editing.

Because there is no source control integration with the Visual Studio Express 2010 editions when you make an edit the file is **not** automatically checked out from source control so it remains read-only, thus causing the problem you have here.

You either need to check out the files before editing the project or force an overwrite and then check out the file after the event. Neither of which is an ideal solution.

Comment: How do I get it to stop asking me to overwrite?  How can I make the error message not show up every time I want to save?

Comment: @user1477388 - Check the files out from Source Safe first. Then they'll be writeable.

Answer (score 1):

When you add items to source control, such a Source Safe, it marks them as `Read Only` to ensure they are not written by anyone who has not checked-out the files.

You need to check-out the file you wish to edit, then edit it, save it, then check it back in.

Source Safe is rather old and not really maintained by Microsoft anymore - consider using something more modern like [Subversion](http://subversion.apache.org/) or [Git](http://git-scm.com/).

Comment: Thanks, your comment was helpful.

Comment: Or, you can use TFS Express. It integrates with Visual Studio Express and is free for up to 5 users. Choose a TFS hosting service if you find the server maintenance is troublesome.

Comment: My best options are to use TFS Express (team foundation server) or use subversion or git?  Is TFS Express the easiest option in terms of setup and use?

Comment: @user1477388- There are _many_ options. TFS express might be fastest and most integrated into visual studio.

Comment: One thing to clarify, I have Web Developer Express.  I'm not sure if that's the same as Visual Studio express.  Do you know for sure?  From what I've read, there is nothing compatible with visual web developer in terms of source control.  Thanks.

Comment: @user1477388 - It is one of the Express versions of Visual Studio. I don't know if the express editions integrate with version control within the IDE.